# Auth. error when trying to query to my PostgreSQL on Azure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, authentication

Im making an API to insert data into my PostgreSQL database hosted at Azure, I have disable SSL and added firewall exceptions in order to secure the conexion, but Im still having an Authentication error when trying to make a POST request, this is the error log:
[image]

I think all the credentials I have to provide are in correct:
[image]

This is the code of the API:
Am I missing something? Some light would be apreciate.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
    user: "LuisFulcrum@sensors",
    host: "sensors.postgres.database.azure.com",
    database: "postgres",
    password: "notTheRealPassword",
    port: 5432
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running, listening to port 8000`);
});

app.post("/api/v1/nodo2059e7", (req, res) => {
    const { label, status, priority } = req.body;
    pool.query(
        "INSERT INTO nodo2059e7(fecha, temperatura, humedad, presionatmosferica, pm1, pm2, pm10) VALUES (NOW(),1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1);",
        [label, status, priority],
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            res.sendStatus(201);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the error is obvious that you provided the wrong password. I also tested your code on my side using my on Azure Postgres SQL:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
    user: "mgr@stanpgtest",
    host: "stanpgtest.postgres.database.azure.com",
    database: "my db name",
    password: "my pass",
    port: 5432
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running, listening to port 8000`);
});

app.post("/api/v1/nodo2059e7", (req, res) => {
    const { label, status, priority } = req.body;
    pool.query(
        "select now()",
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            }
            res.send(results);
        }
    );
});
```

everything works as excepted :

[image]

Just try to reset your password on Azure portal and try again:

[image]

Comment: I have already reset the password and it did not work. so I just created a new PostgreSQL Server with a new DB and works now for some reason...